# I am not sure where to continue after copying the code off youtube api

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I am currently running through this guide to get started with youtube api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python In step 2 where I copy their sample code, the instruction says to copy my api key and replace the YOUR_API_KEY string in the sample code. However there is no YOUR_API_KEY in the sample code

here is the sample code they provide, and i could not find the api_key section. I already have my client_secret.json file but when i replaced client_secrets_file it still would not execute

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.search.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET_FILE.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.search().list(
        part="snippet",
        maxResults=25,
        q="surfing"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Did you skip Step 1?

Comment: Google isn't great about keeping this stuff consistent and up to date.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica For real, besides not being up to date it's just a labyrinth to find the right, *relevant* info on their API.  Just too busy deprecating "old" products for the "new" and dazzles.

Answer (score 1):

The quickstart guide doesn't seem to be up to date. It says there should be a "Credentials" pulldown where you were supposed to select "API key" to get the code sample that uses an API key, but there is no such pulldown.

Instead, in the place where you got the sample code, you need to uncheck the "Google OAuth 2.0" box. (I had to edit and un-edit the "part" field to get the code to refresh, too.) That produces the following, different sample code, which has the expected `YOUR_API_KEY` placeholder:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import googleapiclient.discovery

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        id="UC_x5XG1OV2P6uZZ5FSM9Ttw"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then you can fill in your own API key.